# how to set tag for actionsheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags

I'm trying to set a tag to enable multiple actionsheets in my iOS app but where should I declare it and how?

```
[actionSheet setTag:kActionSheet1];
```

this in what i put in .m but it needs to be declared

Comment: Tag is an integervalue. Have you defined `int kActionSheet1 = 1;` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
[asheet setTag:11];
[asheet showInView:self.view];
```

and here some Tutorial.

[iOS Quick Tip: Create a Dynamic Action Sheet](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-create-a-dynamic-action-sheet/)

[UIActionSheet and UIActionSheetDelegate](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uiactionsheet_uiactionsheetdelegate/)

Comment: You should not set the action sheet's frame and it is probably best to call `showInView:` last.